# Java checkerboard, odd/even % 2 panel

Tags: java

I have successfully got a checkerboard to be put together using colored panels, but only when the user will input odd numbers for the rows and columns. Otherwise when inputing even numbers it just shows alternating colored columns. I'm struggling to figure out how to write a short segment that checks to see if it's odd or even by using the **%2=0**, with the result of even changing the color. Below is my code. Thanks, and take it easy on me I'm very new to programming! :-)

Also, I've created a separate ColorPanel class to build the colored panel, and then pull into into my main program. I didn't bother putting that code below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Checkerboard extends JPanel{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame chBoard = new JFrame();
    chBoard.setTitle("Checkerboard");
    chBoard.setSize(800,800);
    chBoard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of rows", "5");
    if (inputStr == null) return;
    int row = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);

    inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of columns", "5");
    if (inputStr == null) return;
    int col = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);

    Container pane = chBoard.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));

    Color BoxColor = Color.red;

    for ( int counter = 1;  counter <= row * col;  counter++ )
      {
        if (BoxColor == Color.red)
             BoxColor = Color.black;
        else
             BoxColor = Color.red;

        ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(BoxColor);
        pane.add(panel);
      }

    chBoard.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
for ( int x = 0;  x < row;  x++ ) {
    for(int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
        if((x + y)%2 == 0) {
            BoxColor = Color.red;
        } else {
            BoxColor = Color.black;
        }

        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, I'm new to programming but I'm really enjoying the learning experience. I hope this helps other people in their learning experience.

Anyways, I suppose I created more work for myself with the separate ColorPanel class. So instead of creating a separate ColorPanel class to build the colored panel, I just changed it to use the preexisting JPanel class to create the panel inside the main program. So instead of:

```
ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(BoxColor);
```

*+ the ColorPanel class*...

**I put:**

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(BoxColor);
```

within the main program and deleted the additional ColorPanel class.

Sorry for the redundancy, just wanting to explain myself clearly.

Also, thanks to Jason he really helped me figure out the idea of using the two

```
int x & y
```

to count the

```
row & col
```

and then add them together which enabled me to use the

```
%2=0
```

to figure out whether I was on the odd or even panel.

Hope this helps someone! :-)

Final code looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Checkerboard extends JPanel{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame chBoard = new JFrame();
    chBoard.setTitle("Checkerboard");
    chBoard.setSize(800,800);
    chBoard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of rows", "5");
    if (inputStr == null) return;
    int row = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);

    inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of columns", "5");
    if (inputStr == null) return;
    int col = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);

    Container pane = chBoard.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));

    Color BoxColor = Color.red;

    for ( int x = 0;  x < row;  x++ ) {
        for(int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            if((x + y)%2 == 0) {
                BoxColor = Color.red;}
            else{
             BoxColor = Color.black;}

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(BoxColor);

        pane.add(panel);
      }

    chBoard.setVisible(true);
}
}
}
```